# Check if a user goes back to a Fragment of a TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, android-tablayout

I have two Fragments in a TabLayout.
In one Fragment there is a method which changes some values using the SharedPreferences.
When I change the values I always update the Textviews.
This works fine.
But when I go back into my first Fragment, I have the old values, which has been updated in the `OnCreateView()` method.

How I can check if a user goes back to the Fragment and updates the TextViews?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the onResume method of the fragment and inside onResume re-read the values stored in Preferences or you can use a EventBus to propagate the changes or Use RxJava to change reactivily.

Answer (score 0):

mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfTabs);

This may help

Comment: No, because the Minimum Limit is 3